# Removing Duplicate values within a Query when Distinct doesn't work? SQL

Tags: sql

Here is the current query I am running.

```
select c.customer_name, c.city, c.credit_limit, sum(ol.quoted_price)
from   customer c, order_line ol, (select order_num from order_line where part_num = 'AT94') t1
where ol.order_num = t1.order_num and customer_num in ( select customer_num
    from orders
    where order_num in (select t1.order_num
         from order_line,(select order_num from order_line where part_num = 'AT94') t1
         INNER JOIN 
         (select order_num from order_line where part_num = 'BV06') t2
         on t1.order_num = t2.order_num
         where t1.order_num = order_line.order_num
         group by t1.order_num))
group by t1.order_num, c.customer_name, c.city, c.credit_limit
```

The current output I am receiving is:

[image]

I wish to obviously remove the duplication located in the output and currently have no idea how to do so. I have tried using unique in the multiple sub-queries with no success.

Any help is great! Thanks.

Here is the database creation.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
   CUSTOMER_NUM CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
   STREET CHAR(15),
   CITY CHAR(15) DEFAULT 'Ottawa',
   PROVINCE CHAR(3),
   ZIP CHAR(5),
   BALANCE DECIMAL(8,2),
   CREDIT_LIMIT DECIMAL(8,2),
   REP_NUM CHAR(2) 
   CONSTRAINT CHK_Limit CHECK (CREDIT_LIMIT >= BALANCE)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
   ORDER_NUM CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
   ORDER_DATE DATE,
   CUSTOMER_NUM CHAR(3) 
);

CREATE TABLE PART
(
   PART_NUM CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   DESCRIPTION CHAR(15),
   ON_HAND DECIMAL(4,0),
   CLASS CHAR(2),
   WAREHOUSE CHAR(1),
   PRICE DECIMAL(6,2) 
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE
(
   ORDER_NUM CHAR(5),
   PART_NUM CHAR(4),
   NUM_ORDERED DECIMAL(3,0),
   QUOTED_PRICE DECIMAL(6,2),
   PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUM, PART_NUM)
);
```

The solution I would like where the order does not matter for the column:

```
Al's.. | Barrhaven | 7500.00  | 21.95
John.. | Toronto   | 10000.00 | 311.95
```

All data used. Quite a large sum of text. Just decided Pastebin instead of making this question that much longer.

https://pastebin.com/ASBzqcJq

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Remove the `t1.order_num` from `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to see which customer has bought both of parts_numb AT94 and BV06. The issue you're facing is that your query returning duplicated rows, this is because your query already have some redundancy. Which made me go back and check the giving results manually to get the correct results out of the sample that you've provided.

```
SELECT
    ol.ORDER_NUM, 
    c.customer_name, 
    c.city, 
    c.credit_limit, 
    sum(ol.quoted_price)
FROM #order_line ol
INNER JOIN #Orders o ON  o.order_num = ol.order_num
JOIN (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM #ORDER_LINE WHERE part_num = 'AT94') t1 ON t1.ORDER_NUM =  o.ORDER_NUM
JOIN (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM #ORDER_LINE WHERE part_num = 'BV06') t2 ON t2.ORDER_NUM =  o.ORDER_NUM
INNER JOIN #customer c ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
WHERE 
    ol.ORDER_NUM IN(t1.ORDER_NUM) 
AND ol.ORDER_NUM IN(t2.ORDER_NUM)
GROUP BY
    ol.ORDER_NUM,  
    c.customer_name, 
    c.city, 
    c.credit_limit
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71dd7/1)

Hope this will save your day

Comment: There is a table schema and sample data.

Comment: `Al's.. | Barrhaven | 7500.00  | 816.90

John.. | Toronto   | 10000.00 | 816.90`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your result set already has distinct records. Your result set does not have any two rows with exactly same values. What is the output you are expecting? I am not sure what your requirement is. But I think the join between customer number in Customer table and Customer number in Orders table is missing.
Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select C.customer_name, C.city, C.credit_limit, sum(OL.quoted_price)
from CUSTOMER C 
join ORDERS O ON C.Customer_num=O.Customer_num
join ORDER_LINE OL on O.Order_num=Ol.Order_num
WHERE part_num in('AT94','BV06')
group by  C.customer_name, C.city, C.credit_limit;
```

[image]

Comment: Added the result I am looking for in the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you want to select the sum numeric which has lower credit_limit in case there are two credit_limit values for the same customer_name?

Comment: if possible, can you please share the sample records in your tables?

Comment: Your GROUP BY statement includes the order number.  Remove it if you only want to see the tally of quoted price by CustName/City/Credit Limit.

Comment: Please don't use answers as comments.

Comment: Vince, I observed that some of your insert queries have one parameter less. e.g. INSERT INTO ORDER_LINE
VALUES
('21623','BV06',410.00); so hoping you had inserted the data properly. Also, please confirm if the solution was helpful or if possible, provide more details on the exact requirement and not just the expected output/result.